# Where should I put free() in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm a bit new to C-programming and I can't seem to understand where should I free the int* array I initialized. I tried to put `free(array)` after I've got what I need but Valgrind still reports a memory leak and an invalid free at the location I proposed. Where should I put the `free(array)` call in this code?

Note: the actual code implementation is removed to make the code simpler while retaining the bug.

```
// C-language code (C99)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fib(int index, int *array, int initBlocks);
int processFib(int index);
int doubleStorage(int **array, int initialBlocks);

int main() {
    int ans = processFib(10);
    printf("ans = %d", ans);
    return 0;
}

// initialises an array and calls the fib(...) function
int processFib(int index) {
    int defaultInitBlocks = 10;
    int *array = calloc(defaultInitBlocks, sizeof(int));
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 1;
    int ans = fib(index, array, defaultInitBlocks);
    free(array); /* Valgrind says InvalidFree here  ----------------------*/
    return ans;
}

// doubles storage of array using realloc
int doubleStorage(int **array, int initialBlocks) {
    int factor = 2;
    int *temp = realloc(*array, factor * initialBlocks * sizeof(int));
    /* Valgrind says the realloc here is a DefinitelyLost memory leak --------*/
    if (!temp) {
        free(*array);
        return -1;
    } else {
        *array = temp;
        for (int i = initialBlocks; i < factor * initialBlocks; i++) {
            (*array)[i] = 0;
        }
        return factor * initialBlocks;
    }
}


// doubles storage if 'index' is greater than array storage. Else, returns 1
int fib(int index, int *array, int initBlocks) {
    if (index >= initBlocks) {
        int newBlocks = doubleStorage(&array, initBlocks);
        return fib(index, array, newBlocks);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: SOLUTION MOVED TO ANSWERS

Comment: Props for using valgrind. Both are correctly stating their cause. The correctness of your `fib` algorithm notwithstanding, `array` in `processFib` should be passed by address into `fib`, the same way you do into `doubleStorage`. Doing so will carry the reallocation state all the way back to `processFib, where the `free` can properly be called as-is.

Comment: You could vastly improve this program by getting rid of dynamic allocation and recursion both.

Comment: Not related to your problem: You should check if the memory allocation of `calloc(defaultInitBlocks, sizeof(int));` was successful by checking `array` for a null pointer. If it is a null pointer, you should implement a error routine.

Comment: Problem solved after putting the double-pointer. And yeah, I should've checked `array` for a null pointer. For the record, C is far from my favorite language.

Comment: @frostrivera19: Please write your solution as an answer below and accept it. StackOverflow is not your typical "form" where you edit "posts" with "answered" or "solved".

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

A double pointer is now used in the fib() function which cleared the Valgrind warning (code below). Heads up to @WhozCraig for his comment.

```
int fib(int index, int **array, int initBlocks) {
    if (index >= initBlocks) {
        int newBlocks = doubleStorage(array, initBlocks);
        return fib(index, array, newBlocks);
    }
    if (array[index] > 0) {
        return (*array)[index];
    } else {
        (*array)[index] = fib(index - 1, array, initBlocks)
                + fib(index - 2, array, initBlocks);
        return (*array)[index];
    }
}
```